# How to display usernames with case sensitive in MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki

I have user named `MyNiCkNaMe` in my MediaWiki and in table `user` I see `user_name=MyNiCkNaMe` but on MediaWiki pages I see it as `Mynickname` is there any way to display it same as in db?

Comment: Look through the MediaWiki code and figure out where it changes the user name.

Comment: On which pages exactly do you see `Mynickname` where exactly?

Comment: That is not MediaWiki's default behavior. Usernames are case-sensitive except for the first letter which is always uppercased. Are you using an external auth extension?

Comment: @Bergi on every page where user name are displayed is always displayed as `Mynickname` instead of `MyNiCkNaMe`

Comment: @MaxSem I use `Auth_phpbb`, but even if I don't use it (on fresh instaled MediaWiki) if I create user `MyNiCkNaMe` it is always displayed as `Mynickname`. I know that first letter is always capital but why all other letter are always lowercase?

Answer (score 0):

In LocalSettings.php include the line

> [$wgRestrictDisplayTitle](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgRestrictDisplayTitle) = false;

Then on the user page use the magic word/parser function [DISPLAYTITLE](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words)

> {{DISPLAYTITLE:User:MyNiCkNaMe}}